# Pause Lead Conversion Process for Validating Account Fields

Tags: lead-conversion

Is there anyway to pause the `Lead` conversion process until some generated `Account` fields being validated?
This is my road block

- When a user creates an account from standard layout we are generating
  a code based on the account name.
- If the generated code equals with
  an existing one let user to edit it;after saving record this code is
  non-editable.
- In `Lead` conversion process it's ok to generate the
  code in a before insert trigger.
- **But no way to let user edit it when duplicates match.**

I'm thinking of going with a custom `Lead` Convert button and let user land into a custom page where the user can view a summary of the new account, but before the account record get inserted. Is there anyway to handle this? I'm using `Database.LeadConvert` and `Database.LeadConvertResult` in my custom VF page controller extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Where are you checking for the duplicate code?. 
Im guessing if you have the validation apex in a "Account Before Insert" trigger, think that this trigger will run when you press the "Convert Lead" button.

The logic is this:

- Lead Convert will create a set of objects, configure them, and run a insert.
- When the Account insert is running, if you have a validation apex on "Account Before Insert" that throws an error (if the duplicated code you are checking happens), it should Stop the convertion and throw the proper error on the Lead page.

My guess is that you should end up on the Lead page with an error telling you to type another code, and I think that's what you want.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with the below approach.

1. Created a VF page with Lead standard controller;in the page action checked for duplicates; redirect to a middle stage page to summarize data.
2. Created a custom button for Lead object and set it's action to calling above page.
3. In the middle stage page let the user to review data and validate the auto generated code (here user can edit it as it wanted)
4. Do the conversion upon user press the `Convert` button in the middle stage page.
5. Set the generated (or user edited) code to an static variable and set it in a `before insert` Account trigger.

Hope this helps someone.